# Multiple conditions if statement syntax in python

Tags: python, if-statement, logical-operators

I have a problem that I know the workaround to, but I don't *understand* why my initial attempt does not work. It's a relatively simple Q on multiple conditions for if-statements.

```
a = np.arange(2)
b = np.arange(5)
c = np.arange(6)

arr = np.array([[i,j,k] for i in a for j in b for k in c])

for row in arr:
    i,j,k = row
    if i != 1 | j != 4 | k != 1: continue
    print(i,j,k)
```

My expectation is that as long as one of the conditions in the if statement evaluates true, then the for loop should continue to the next line.

The output is that it prints

```
0 4 1
0 4 5
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 0 3
1 0 4
1 0 5
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 1 5
1 4 1
1 4 5
```

For example, the very first output, 0 != 1 clearly should evaluate true, therefore it should not print? In fact, the only print I expect to see should be (1,4,1).

I know the solution is

```
if (i,j,k) != (1,4,1): continue
```

However, I am puzzled to why my initial attempt does not work as expected..

Cheers

Comment: `|` is binary or, not logical or.

Comment: Use `or` instead of `|`.

Comment: The other problem is that `|` binds stronger than `!=`.

Comment: I would love to know more. What do you mean by bind?

Also @FredLarson the 'or' worked as expected!

Comment: With bind more he means the preceedence of how operators like `|` and `!=` are evaluated. It's like in math, where `*` has preceedence over `+`and therefore `1*2+3` is different to `1*(2+3)`